# what is a typical way forex brokerages can provide cheap leverage for their customers?

Tags: hedging, fx, market-making, leverage

I'm not very well read in the area of high finance but I'm curious how forex brokerages are able to provide the backing for leverage that they can provide to customers.

Is it possible to do this without charging interest, only making the return on the spread against the rates they can get?

Are there standard algorithms that can be used to this end?

Comment: The high leverage is only for small accounts (under 1 mil), and interest IS charged (and paid). And a lot of positions offset each-other, so the net amount is much smaller.

Comment: I'm curious also what these people are up to? https://www.bitcoinica.com/

Comment: I originally read this is "What is the typical way forex brokers can cheat their customers"! It's called "stop hunting"!

Comment: Apparently, providing all tbis leverage is quite hard...

Comment: It's not hard to provide the leverage, but all leverage is risky. If your upstart broker can't do it then you pay a fee and backup to a bigger broker with the facility. They might also require that they have oversight and run some risk checks on your book. When you get the credit you negotiate lower fees or you do it yourself. Then the CHF/all comes unhinged and you're down the tubes, while you're big brother banker is explaining to shareholders why they didn't see your blow-up coming.

Comment: Not all brokers provides you with real leverage, some of them simply simulate it or at least aggregate clients requests to decrease resulting amount of money for LP - http://forextrading100.com/forex-broker-types-ecn-vs-dma-vs-stp-vs-market-maker/

Comment: @Adal this is not true. As an instructional investor you can get much higher leverage with FX.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, the client only manages their own position, with the client credit line provided by the broker, whereas the broker manages all their clients' positions, using the broker credit line with their provider banks. You can work it out from there. Interest is presumably to do with cash deposits and loans.